# Use mongo positional operator ($) and find in multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let me extend the example [from the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) to:

```js
{
  _id: 4,
  tags: ['good', 'great', 'nice'], 
  grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update all `grade=85` which have also an tag `good`. I would try to use:

```js
db.students.update(
   { tags: "good", "grades.grade": 85 },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
)
```

However, mongo will set the `$` to `0` because the tag `good` is the first in the tag list. This causes the data to change to:

```js
{
  _id: 4,
  tags: ['good', 'great', 'nice'], 
  grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 6 }, //←wrong
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to tell mongo and/or mongoose to use the position in grades to reference the grade?

Comment: what happens if you put grade before tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mongoose` you should create two seperate models. One for `Students` and an other one for `Grades`. Then let `Students` contain references to `Grades`.

This will allow to update single `Grades` easily.

Something like:

```
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tags: [String],
    grades: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Grade'
    }
});

var Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);

var gradeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    grade: Number,
    mean: Number,
    std: Number
});

var Grade = mongoose.model('Grade', studentSchema);
```

Your update code could look like this:

```
Student.find({tags: { $in: ['good'] }}).populate('grades', { grade: 85 }).exec(function(err, students) {
    students.grades.forEach(function(grade) {
        grade.update(null, { std: 6 }, function(err, numAffected) {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Both current answers are good. I solved it in a mixture of both, what suited best for my actual code.

Answer (score 4):

It happened because you use two arrays in a single query document. But unfortunately, it is not supported in MongoDB.

[MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

> The query document should only contain a single condition on the array
>   field being projected. Multiple conditions may override each other
>   internally and lead to undefined behavior.
>
> Under these requirements, the following query is incorrect:
>
> ```
> db.collection.find( { <array>: <value>, <someOtherArray>: <value2> },
>                   { "<array>.$": 1 } )
> ```

You can try to write something like that:

```
db.test.find({tags: "good", "grades.grade": 85 }).forEach(function(doc){ db.test.update(
{_id: doc._id, "grades.grade": 85 },
{ $set: { "grades.$.std" : 88 }}, 
{multi: true})})
```